# Confusion over data structures in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been reading the brilliant Learn You A Haskell and I've come to the chapter on types and type classes. I'm confused as to how you would imitate hierarchy as you would in a classical language.
For example, I know if I want a 'class' of weapons then something like this is possible:

```
data Weapon = 
  Sword  { sharpness :: Int, weight :: Int, name :: String } 
  | Mace { spikeyness :: Int, weight :: Int, name :: String }
  deriving (Eq)
```

Is this a good way to do things?
If this method is correct, then I'm struggling to see how you would implement different behaviour for each constructor: E.g. if you wanted to show a weapon in a different way depending on whether it was a Sword or a Mace...

```
instance Show Weapon where 
  show w = "This is " ++ name w ++ ". It has a weight of " ++ (show $ weight w)
```

I know this is possible, but this function encounters a problem if I try to show all the fields because swords are not spikey and maces are not sharp. How could I create different instances in the Show class for Maces and Swords?

Comment: This is simply a miss use of the show class.  Consider making a `describe : Weapon -> String`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you can pattern-match on the constructor like this:

```
instance Show Weapon where
    show (Sword s w n) = "This is a sword with sharpness " ++ show s ++ ...
    show (Mace s w n ) = "This is a mace with spikeyness " ++ show s ++ ...
```

and you can do it like this but maybe you should start to think what you want to do with your weapons (like hit somebody, something) - so instead you could have functions like `calculateDamage`on them:

```
data Weapon = MkWeapon { calcDamage :: HeroStats -> Enemy -> Damage, ... }
```

And then you can make lot's of weapons, for example:

```
sword :: Weapon
sword = MkWeapon (\ heroStats enemyStats -> strength heroStats - armor enemyStats)
```

or something like this.

Comment: Why have you specified a function in the constructor? I thought constructors were used to set the attributes of a particular data type.

Comment: @Normangorman Functions can be attributes.  Remember, functions are data in Haskell

Answer (score 3):

On a more general note, you may be interested in [Tony Tavener's blog](http://cranialburnout.blogspot.co.uk) about implementing a game in a functional language (OCaml in his case). There are a lot of interesting ideas e.g. [this post in particular](http://cranialburnout.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/database-radiation-hazard.html) demonstrating a modular way of defining a database of game elements with a notion of inheritance.